# Disable toast notification or change error message in google apps script add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, autocomplete, google-apps-script-api

1. I'm working to create an add-on using the Google Apps script. Almost
   everything is completed and working fine.
2. I have a text field of auto-suggestions from the server
   side(basically data will come from the backend through fetch API
   call). Fetch functionality and auto-suggestions everything is working
   fine.
3. But, while fetching the data or typing on the text fields, keep on
   getting "**Server failed to fetch the suggestions**" error toast
   notification.
4. Somehow I need to block(disable) the toast notification or change
   error text to **Loading...**

```
    var txt_search = CardService.newTextInput()
    .setFieldName('txtfield_service')
    .setTitle('Enter Service Name')
    .setHint('Enter at least 4 characters.') 
    .setSuggestionsAction(
      CardService.newAction().setFunctionName("getallservices")
    );
```

[image: snapshot for error message]

Kindly help me on this, I am completely stuck on this issue. Almost everything is ready, the client is telling me to block the error toast notification.

Thanks, In advance.

GopalaKrishnan.R

Comment: What is this function `fetchservices_autosuggestion()`

Comment: Fetch the data through an API call and prepare the auto-suggestion array in the fetchservices_autosuggestion function.

Comment: @Cooper any idea? do you know how to disable to toast notification?

Comment: @Cooper any idea?

Comment: I don't think that's a dialog that google apps script has any control over and I can't reproduce the problem since you did not supply us with a [mcve]